# Problema al generar números aleatorios con rand()

Tags: random, matlab

estoy intentando solucionar un problema en el cual al lanzarse una partícula tiene 3 posibilidades:
1 - Es absorbida por la placa
2 - Rebota
3 - Atraviesa

Las formulas del movimiento de la partícula se realizan mediante el uso de un numero aleatorio (rand()) el caso es que tengo que enumerar las veces que esto pasa con 1000 partículas, aunque al meterlo en un bucle, no genera 1000 veces un numero distinto, es decir 1 por cada iteración sino que genera uno y lo utiliza para los "1000 lanzamientos" por lo que los resultados del contador son o 1000 en uno o 1000 en otro o un numero aleatorio entre 150 y 250 por lo que he visto (otra cosa que no entiendo la verdad)

¿Cómo podría hacer para resolver esto?

Muchas gracias de antemano y dejo el código aquí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. el código se comparte como texto. Por ejemplo, en esa imagen no se ve de dónde sale `rand`

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
 Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar estar usando "rand" fuera del bucle este solo se esta ejecutando una sola vez.

Primero crea los 1000 números aleatorios y aplicalos posteriormente en tu ciclo for

A la función "rand" le puedes pasar argumentos de varias maneras
por ejemplo

rand(n) - te devuelve una matriz de números aleatorios de dimensiones nxn

En tu caso, puedes usar el comando X = rand(10,10) para generar una matriz de dimensiones de 10x10

Tu variable X contiene este array. Aquí puede hacer un barrido con dos for anhidados o hacer una multiplicación/división por elementos utilizando un punto antes del operador

Es decir:

C = A.*B

Recomendaciónn: En matlab en la ventana de comandos puedes teclear `help` + "la función con la que tienes duda", lo cual te abrir un ventana con información relevante a dicha función.